# Logic question in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logic, predicate-logic, higher-order-logic

I thought about posting some minor insecurities and some main doubts i have on a particular topic.

Let R with the usual metric be a metric space, $A \subseteq R$ , $f:A\to R$ and p is a limit point of A.

Consider the limit of f as its dependent variable on the A-domain tends to the point p being defined with the common $\delta-\varepsilon$  definition.

I have the following sequence characterization .

$P_1$  iff  $P_2$

Where
$P_1$ = $\exists L \in R ( lim_{x\to p}f(x) = L)$ .
$P_2$ = $\exists L \in R $ ( for every sequence eventually non-constant sequence $x_n \in A$ converging to p, $f(x_n)$ converges to L ).

Now, i'm atempting to negate the previous equivalence in order to get a criterium for the non-existence of the functional limit    .

I guess that $\neg P_1$ would become "$\forall L \in R ( lim_{x\to p}f(x) \neq L) $. 
In words, it would become "$lim_{x\to p}f(x)$ doesn't exist ".
Is that correct ?    **(Insecurity #1)**

But my problem lies on $P_2$.
The natural negation that comes to me would be :
"$\forall L\in Y$ (there exists a eventually non-constant sequence $x_n \in A$ converging to p such that $f(x_n)\neq L$ ) .
In words, it would become equivalent to "there exists an eventually non-constant sequence $x_n \in A$ converging to p such that $f(x_n)$ doesn't converge".
Is that reasoning correct ?  **(Insecurity #2)**

Now, i have read that there is some other proposition $P_3$ that is is also equivalent to  $\neg P_2$, namely,  :
"there exists eventually non-constant sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ $\in A$ converging to p such that $lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) \neq  lim_{n\to \infty} f(y_n)$ ".

I'm curious on this alternative equivalence.   I can see how $\neg P_2$ iff $P_3$ on the context of sequences :
If $\neg P_2$ is true, then letting the sequence that satisfies it be $x_n$,  then $P_3$ will be true for any eventually non constant sequence $y_n$ converging to p.
If $P_3$ is true, then we can build a sequence $z_n$ such that $f(z_n)$ won't converge by defining $z_{2n} = x_n  ,  z_{2n+1}=y_n$, and which will satisfy $\neg P_2$ .
Is that correct ? **(#Doubt 1)**

But i'm curious on the generality of that equivalence.  Is it certain that the $\neg P_2$ and $P_3$ propositions can not be expressed formally with first order logic, but i guess that the formal system of higher order logic would be able to formally express them.
So, would there be a logical axiom of higher order logic representing generally the equivalence that was presented on the context of sequences between $\neg P_2$ and $P_3$
Or is the generality of that equivalence much more simple than i'm making ? **(#Doubt 2)**   .

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points, in the order I think of them:

- For $P_2$, you should have $\lim_{n \to \infty }f(x_n) = L$
- Your negation of $P_1$ is correct
- The verbal of $P_2$ should be "for every $L$, there exists a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $L$"
- $P_3$ assumes that we can construct *some* sequence that converges to two non-equal things.  That is, we have to assume that there are an $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $f(x_n)$ and $f(y_n)$ *are convergent* and have non-equal limits.
- However, assuming we have such an $x_n$ and $y_n$ exist, we can indeed make a $z_n$ as you suggest, so that $P_1 \iff P_2 \implies \neg P_3$

For an example of that convergence only existing in the one direction, consider
$$
f(x) = 1/x
$$
$f$ has no limit at $0$, but $P_3$ is not true.

Comment: You touched on a doubt i have.  I was thinking that even in the case where $lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)$ doesn't exist,  $f(x_n)$ would satisfy the proposition   $lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) \neq lim_{n\to \infty} f(y_n)$, for any sequence $f(y_n)$, be it convergent or not.

Comment: Right. In my example, $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)$ doesn't exist for any $x_n$

Comment: Also, what is the difference between "for every L in Y, there exists a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)$ does not converge to L" and " there exists a sequence $x_n$ in Y that does not converge ? "

Comment: There is no difference in the end, but showing that they are equivalent is non-trivial. That is, we have to note that if we have sequences converging to two different limits, we can construct a sequence converging to no limit. Also, I don't know where the "eventually non-constant" bit was supposed to factor in.

Comment: I see. The "eventually non-constant" bit i guess was some requirement i put on the sequence so that $P_2$ would only work for p as a limit point of A ( if p was an isolated point of A, then the only sequences converging to it would be eventually constant sequences converging to p ). Is that right or is that actually unnecessary/an error ?

Comment: Actually, it seems that your idea here is the [traditional way to go](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27429/why-not-define-limits-to-include-isolated-points), my mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those insigths, i solved my doubt now.