Question about limits and continuity when the function isn't defined in a region.
Let's say I have a function that looks something like this.
$$ 
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
      x & x\leq 0 \\
      1 & x=1 \\
      x & x\ge 2 
\end{cases}
$$
What would the values of $$\lim_{x\to1^-} f(x)$$ and $$\lim_{x\to1^+} f(x)$$ be? My guess is that it should be $0$ and $2$, respectively because we can ignore the regions $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 2)$ since the function isn't defined there.
Also, is the function continuous at $x = 1$?
What if I change the function to
$$ 
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
      1 & x\leq 0 \\
      1 & x=1 \\
      1 & x\ge 2 
\end{cases}
$$
? What would the limits be now? Would this new function be continuous?
Apologies if a similar question has been asked before. I didn't find anything relevant based on my searches.
My definition of limit is this:
$$\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists\delta>0\ \forall x\in dom(f)\ (0 < |x - a| <\delta \implies |f(x) - l| < \epsilon)$$
So for the second case, if $l = 1$, for every $\epsilon\gt0$, we can choose $ = 2$, and we'll have $(0<|−|< ⟹ |()−|<)$. So limit at $1$ should be $1$. Is there a flaw in my understanding?

What is your definition of limit? Can the limit exist (by definition) at an isolated point?

Both functions are continuous but limit at $x=1$ doesn't exist.

Refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/455296/505767

@user my definition of limit is this: ∀>0 ∃>0 ∀ (0<|−|< ⟹ |()−|<)
So for the second case, if  = 1, for every >0, we can choose  = 2, and we'll have (0<|−|< ⟹ |()−|<). So Iimit at 1 should be 1. Is there a flaw in my understanding?

At an isolated point this is not true $\forall x$ with $0<|x-a|<\delta$, in other words we need that $x=a$ is an accumulation point.

@user I'm sorry but why is this not true? Just to clarify, when we say ∀x, we mean ∀x in $domain(f)$, right?

Refer to what discussed here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27429/505767

The key point is that the definition works fine when $x=a$ is an accumulation point but for isolated points it doesn't work, you are right $L=1$ is the limit but also $L=2$ works by $\delta=1/2$.

You should add your first coment in your question.

@user added the comment! And thank you for the clarification! It makes sense now!

You are welcome! Bye

According to the definition of right (left) limits:let E and X are metric space ,d is the metric function of E$f:E \to X$, for all $\varepsilon$>0,exist $\delta$, so that , for all $x\in E$ that satisfy $0<x-x^0<\delta (0<x^0-x<\delta)$ , $|f(x)-f(x^0)|<\varepsilon$, so $\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}f(x)$does not exist (precisely,it is not defined, but if we admit $x=x^0$, the limit is 1 ),so do others.
On the other side,the definition of continous at $x^0$ is: for all $\varepsilon$>0,exist $\delta$, so that , for all $x\in E$ that satisfy $d(x,x^0)<\delta$, $d(f(x),f(x^0))<\varepsilon$,so both of the answers
are yes.
